# Trigger a mail when mysql server is down

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysql-error-1064

I have hosted on of my web application on Rackspace server. It is having DB on its localhost.
I don't know why my DB shutdown unexpectedly and on my production server it displays Error establishing DB connection. 
When I restart the mysql server it works fine. `service mysql restart`.

Can we trigger a mail whenever our mysql server is down ?

Where I need to do the setting.

Should I write a function that check DB connection for every 5section and if not okay it will trigger a mail?

Any other best solution?

Server Configuration :

`OS : Ubuntu 14.04
RAM : 8GB
PHP version : 5.3.10
MYSQL version : 5.5.40`

Comment: write shell script...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is called a "watchdog".

Yes, it is typically implemented by polling the service to be monitored on a regular base, but a lower frequency should be fine. You are not interested in a few seconds here. You could use a `cron` job for the purpose.

Polling does not necessarily mean you have to implement a fully fledged database connection. Maybe a socket test is enough to confirm that the server is still up and responding. That would require much less resources, but obviously the resulting statement is limited too.

Another and much more powerful approach is to use a monitoring solution like `nagios` or `zabbix` which allow to monitor arbitrary services, systems, things, visualize the result over time and send various forms of alarms and triggers.

A third alternative for your specific situation is to implement an error handler for your application that sends the message. This is well possible, since a failing database connection is not a fatal issue, so your script continues to be executed.

---

My personal suggestion is to start using a monitoring solution if you act in a professional environment, if you do business online.

Comment: If I am doing using a cron and in the mail being sent, I want to send the error message also. How can I get the error message like why my mysql server gets down?

Comment: It is not likely that you will succeed in implementing this. Reason is that the issue at hand is arbitrary: all you know when the server is down is that the server is down. There _might_ be entries in the database servers log files. But it _might_ also have silently crashed. The firewall _might_ have been altered, maybe accidentally, the network routing _might_ have been altered outside the system. It _might_ be that you can draw conclusions from the error message in the http servers log files. You see, this is a question of investigation, you cannot automate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pm2-mysql](https://github.com/pm2-hive/pm2-mysql)

```
pm2 install pm2-mysql
```

And connect it via https://keymetrics.io/ there you will be notified if it goes down

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are very OK.

You could also consider uptimerobot.com or pingdom.com or any other website monitoring solutions. I personally use both of these two. I have a special url which tests db, external apis, redis and few more things and this url is called by uptime robot.

These tools will not only let you know that something is wrong, but also you may get an overall statistics about downtime(s).

They also offer alternative ways of informing you about the problem, to mention an SMS.

Comment: Sure, possible. But does one really want to expose the own (business critical) server with its internal knowledge to some outside service company one does actually not have any idea of whether they can be trusted? What they do with the information? Who has access to that information? I personally would not do that...

Comment: @arkascha In my case what is "exposed" to an outside company is a "cryptic" message like "7AjNkL OK" or "7AjNkL DOWN". That's enough to setup alerting rules.

Comment: So you need an additional logic executed on your system itself? If so, what is the advantage of using an additional, external service to trigger that logic compared to a simple, local cron job?

Comment: @arkascha 
If your VM/VPS is down completely (it happend to my KVM in the past) your local cron wouldn't be running and you may never notice there is any problem. But, again, I am just saying what works for me, based on my experience.

Comment: @arkascha It's quite similar to a usual "health-check", I've never seen health-checks being run from the local machine.

Answer (score -1):

Try using cronjobs create a php page in which create connection to database if connection is successful then its ok. If connection is unsuccessful send email.

```
if(! $conn ) {
  //die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  // send email
```

}